# Error: Call to undefined function Tests\factory()

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel I have written the following test:

```
    public function testUserCanCreateAssortment()
    {
        $this->signIn();

        $this->get('/assortments/create')->assertStatus(200);

        $this->followingRedirects()
            ->post('/assortments', $attributes = Assortment::factory()->raw())
            ->assertSee($attributes['title'])
            ->assertSee($attributes['description']);
    }
}
```

When I run it with the command `phpunit --filter testUserCanCreateItem` I get the following error:

`Error: Call to undefined function Tests\factory()`

No idea what is causing it. I have looked at my factories and my `testcase.php` but I could not find a solution. What am I doing wrong?

My `testcase.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    protected function signIn($user = null)
    {
        $user = $user ?: User::factory()->create();

        $this->actingAs($user);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

Here the lines the error provides:

`/var/www/tests/TestCase.php:13`

`/var/www/tests/Feature/ItemTest.php:29`

Comment: Laravel 8.0 removed the `factory()` method, you have to use `User::factory()->create();` instead of `factory('App\User')->create();` or install the [legacy factory package](https://github.com/laravel/legacy-factories).

Comment: @Remul check the edit. I tried that but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Are you using the `factory()` method anywhere else in your code?

Comment: Usually, the full and exact error message contains the file and line number causing that error - can you share it?

Comment: check the edit @NicoHaase

Comment: For clarification: `User` is another class in that `Tests` namespace? And this class in this exact namespace contains a `factory` method?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes.

Comment: Can you share that `User` class? Also, do you have any idea why you call `User::factory()` and the error message complains about calling `Tests\factory()`?

Comment: @NicoHaase I found the solution. Check my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Laravel 8, the `factory` helper is no longer available. Your `testcase` model class should use HasFactory trait, then you can use your factory like this:

```
testcase::factory()->count(50)->create();
```

*Please note that you should also update your call to User factory: factory('App\User')->create()->id;*

Here is the relevant documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#creating-models

However, if you prefer to use the Laravel 7.x style factories, you can use the package laravel/legacy-factories You may install it with composer:

```
composer require laravel/legacy-factories
```

Comment: Please don't consider installing a dependency that is there to fix legacy deprecations. That is making the technical debt even bigger. When someone upgrades to a new major version of, they should expect to have fixed their deprecations and let the userland code meet the new version's interface contracts.

Answer (score 1):

Guys I found the solution to my answer.

I needed to add the model name in my `AssortmentFactory`. So I did:

`protected $model = Assortment::class;`

and I also needed to import the model by doing `use App/Models/Assortment`.

In the `UserFactory` I also needed to import the model by doing `App/Models/Assortment`.

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to specify that you are using an other class.

Did you write `use Assortment` or `use \Assortment` above ?

You can also use the manager to find the class you are using

Comment: In my test I have not done `use Assortment` or `use \Assortment` at all. But I did do `use App\Models\Assortments;` which did not change anything

Answer (score -1):

First run this command `composer require laravel/legacy-factories`

```
public function YourMethodName()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();
        $this->actingAs($user);

        //code...
    }
```